# Prove that the series is less than the square of a series.

Tags: real-analysis

Prove that $(\sum_{i=1}^n a_i)^2 \leq n \sum_{i=1}^na_i^2$ for $a_1, ..., a_n$. Hint: You may want to use the triangle inequality or Cauchy-Shwartz inequality.

I'm trying to prove this preposition. here's what I've done so far...

$(\sum_{i=1}^n a_i)^2$ = $\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n a_ia_j$

Then for each $i$, $\sum_{j=1}^n a_ia_j = \langle a_i, a\rangle$ (Dot product)

By Cauchy Shwartz, $\langle a_i, a_j\rangle \leq ||a_i||\:||a||  $

To me it looks like this is a "nested for loop" which means there will be an $n$ number of dot products producted, or $n \cdot ||a|| \: ||a||$

But I'm stuck, so please help and don't really know what direction this proof is going in.

Thanks.

Comment: What is the dot product of $a_i$ and $a$?  Isn't $a_i$ a number?

Comment: I'm fixing $a_i$ and doing the product over all of $a$ for each $a_n$ in the sequence.

Comment: It appears that you're doing $\langle a_i\vec{1},a\rangle$ where $\vec{1}$ is the vector of all $1$'s.  What you have written is not a dot product since the objects are not the correct type.

Comment: Oh, then what would you recommend I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Continuing on from your first equality,
$$ \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^n a_i a_j \leq \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^n | a_i a_j | \leq \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^n \frac{a_i^2 + a_j^2}{2} = \frac{n}{2}\sum_{i=1} a_i^2 + \frac{n}{2}\sum_{j=1} a_j^2 = n \sum_{i=1}^n a_i^2 $$
by the AM–GM inequality.

Comment: How did you know to use the Am-Gm inequality? It made for a very neat proof.

Comment: I saw a product, knew I wanted squares, and tried AM–GM. And then I noticed the sums politely split up. It becomes instinctive when you look at inequalities nearly every day. :)

Comment: Ah, the hint advised using a triangle inequality or cauchy-shwartz, neither of which I could figure out how to use. Any ideas in terms of using those?

Comment: If $\underline{1}=(1,1,\dots,1)$ with $n$ components, Cauchy–Schwarz gives $$ \langle a,\underline{1} \rangle^2  \leq \langle a,a \rangle \langle \underline{1},\underline{1} \rangle.  $$ Work out what the left and right-hand side are for $\langle u,v\rangle = \sum_{i=1}^n u_i v_i$ and you get your inequality.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

Consider the vectors $\underbrace{(1,1,\dots,1)}_{n\;1\text{s}}$ and $\;(a_1, a_2,\dots,a_n)$.

Comment: I am not really sure what you mean.

Comment: Apply Cauchy-Schwarz to these vectors.